# Detecting if an ObservableCollection has been modified

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I have a DataGrid nested in a DockPanel. The DockPanel serves as a data context:

```
DockPanel1.DataContext = GetData();
```

The GetData() method returns an ObservableCollection.

The ObservableCollection can be modified in the DataGrid as well as in a few textboxes nested in the DockPanel. I also navigate through the collection using a DataView.

I'd like to detect if the collection has been modified and warn a user when he/she tries to close the application without saving data.

Is there any built-in mechanism that I could use (a kind of "IsDirty" flag on the collection or on the view)? If not, I guess I will have to monitor all the controls and detect any changes manually.

Thanks,
Leszek

Answer (score 3):

In order to detect changes in the collection itself, you would have to attach a [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) handler. If you also need to detect changes in the objects contained in the collection, you would have to attach [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) handlers to every object (provided that the objects implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

An implementation would basically look like this:

```
var collection = GetData();
collection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

...

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            AddPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            RemovePropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            RemovePropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
            AddPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            break;
    }

    ...
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

private void AddPropertyChanged(IEnumerable items)
{
    if (items != null)
    {
        foreach (var obj in items.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
        {
            obj.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}

private void RemovePropertyChanged(IEnumerable items)
{
    if (items != null)
    {
        foreach (var obj in items.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
        {
            obj.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on Clemens' answer above, here's the simple way to use these events (on the collection, and on the contained items) to implement an IsDirty flag such as you described:

```
public class DirtyCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isDirty = false;

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return this.isDirty; }
    }

    public void Clean()
    {
        this.isDirty = false;
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // We aren't concerned with how the collection changed, just that it did.
        this.isDirty = true;

        // But we do need to add the handlers to detect property changes on each item.
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                this.AddPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                this.RemovePropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                this.RemovePropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
                this.AddPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
                break;
        }

        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    private void AddPropertyChanged(IEnumerable items)
    {
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var obj in items.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                obj.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void RemovePropertyChanged(IEnumerable items)
    {
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var obj in items.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                obj.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // A property of a contained item has changed.
        this.isDirty = true;
    }
}
```

The code should be fairly self-explanatory.

You can, of course, remove the "where T : INotifyPropertyChanged" to allow objects that don't implement that interface to be stored in the collection, but then you won't be notified of any property changes on them, as without that interface, they can't notify you of them.

And should you want to keep track of not only that the collection is dirty but also how, some additions in OnCollectionChanged and OnItemPropertyChanged to record the information passed in the event args would do that nicely.

Comment: Thanks Clemens and Cerebrate. This is a very good solutions that I will use in new projects.

Regarding the current project, it does not seem I can use it without rework. First of all, I already have a bunch of ObservableCollections serialized on a disc. When I try to deserlize them and cast to DirtyCollection - an exception is thrown "Invalid cast".

Second, my DirtyCollection has a member - an ObservableCollection that also would need to be a DirtyCollection. In other words I have a collection of collections.

I just hoped that there would be a simple out-of-the box method to do it.