# IsDirty() flushes new Collection entities

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, entities

I have a WPF application and am using NHibernate. My question is how do I manage change?

I am not completely sure about the behavior of the IsDirty.

This [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg23084.html) describes my problem. The problem list all the information of current environment.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to address a client side problem using server side technology. Create a viewmodel and put your data in an ObservableCollection and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the entities as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13936551/1045728)

This way you separate the Dirty() logic from NHibernate and make it a "pure" WPF/client issue. In the link it is described in both answers how you can track additions and deletions to/from the collection as well as changes to the properties of the items.

When you are ready to persists your data you hand the dirty records to NHibernate.